woocommerce permalinks like "?p=%post_id%"
I need to use a permalink to a product page in woocommerce like "?p=%post-id"
The settings do not seem to work because I try this I get a link like "?p=15/name_of_product"
While playing around I found out that the if the function wp_force_plain_post_permalink() in wp-includes/link-template.php returns true, I get the permalink I want (more or less)
It will return:
?post_type=product&p=15 (in case of a product)
?page_id=2 (in case of a page)
However I guess changing link-template.php should not be done because it would be overwritten in case of an update?
What is the best way to get what I want and if possible only a link with "?p=15"

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Could you provide a screenshot of the permalinks structure you have in your settings? Try using Post name, under Permalink structure -> Post name
